# Reset select value depending on siblings state in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have two siblings and one is watching the state of another.

```
<Controller
   control={control}
   name="selectedBirthYear"
   defaultValue={years[0]}
   render={({ field }) => (
     <SelectBirthYear
       field={field}
       years={years}
       value={selectedYear}
       defaultValue={selectedYear}
       onChange={useEffect(() => {setSelectedYear(field.value)})}
    />
   )}
/>
```

and

```
<Controller
       control={control}
       name="selectedBirthMonth"
       defaultValue={months[0]}
       render={({ field }) => (
         <SelectBirthMonth
           field={field}
           startYear={startYear}
           selectedYear={selectedYear}
           months={months}
           value={selectedMonth}
           defaultValue={selectedMonth}
           reducedMonths={reducedMonths}
           onChange={useEffect(() => setSelectedMonth(field.value))}
        />
     )}
/>
```

These two components are part of a Form parent. But, the issue is, that my useEffect, which watches year change, is not firing in combination with the Controller:

```
const watchYearChange = () => {
    if(Number(selectedYear.name) == startYear){
      setSelectedMonth(reducedMonths[reducedMonths.length - 1]);
    }
};
useEffect(() => watchYearChange(), [selectedYear])
```

So, I was thinking to put this logic inside of the component itself and 'reset' the value of month on year change (Number(selectedYear.name) == startYear)

I've been experimenting, but for now with no success.

```
export const SelectBirthMonth = ({
  startYear,
  selectedYear,
  months,
  field,
  selectedMonth,
  setSelectedMonth,
  reducedMonths}) => {
  const { onChange, value } = field;

  const watchYearChange = () => {
    if(Number(selectedYear.name) == startYear){
      setSelectedMonth(reducedMonths[reducedMonths.length - 1]);
    }
    console.log(reducedMonths[reducedMonths.length - 1]);
  };

  useEffect(() => watchYearChange(), [selectedYear])
  return (
    <Listbox value={Number(selectedYear.name) == startYear ? value == reducedMonths[reducedMonths.length - 1] : value} onChange={onChange}>
      
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <Listbox.Label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Geburtsmonat</Listbox.Label>
          <div className="mt-1 relative">
            <Listbox.Button className="bg-white relative w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-yellow-500 focus:border-yellow-500 sm:text-sm">
              <span className="block truncate">{value?.name}</span>
              <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
                <SelectorIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
              </span>
            </Listbox.Button>

            <Transition
              show={open}
              as={Fragment}
              leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <Listbox.Options
                static
                className="absolute z-10 mt-1 w-full bg-white shadow-lg max-h-60 rounded-md py-1 text-base ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-auto focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
              >
                { Number(selectedYear.name) == startYear ? reducedMonths.map((month) => (
                  <ListboxOption
                    key={month.id}
                    value={month}
                    date={month.name}
                  >
                  </ListboxOption>
                )) : months.map((month) => (
                  <ListboxOption
                    key={month.id}
                    value={month}
                    date={month.name}
                  >
                  </ListboxOption>
                ))
              }
              </Listbox.Options>
            </Transition>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </Listbox>
  )
}
```

Any ideas, how to 'reset' value, which is already coming from field of react hook form? I am really stuck.

Comment: There are some questions about your implementaion. 1) why are you using the `useEffect` in `onChange` method?  2) do you tried to use the `useWatch` from `react-hook-form` to get the value of `selectedBirthYear` and `selectedBirthMonth`? 3) did you check your `useEffect` firing with change on `selectedYear` by adding a `console.log` inside it?